# Changing Nginx server location for ISPConfig

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I installed ISPConfig on Ubuntu. It was configured for one NGinx install but I had to move to a different Nginx install. Now how can I make ISPConfig aware of this new location and forget about the other one?
Thanks!

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are asking, but, if you want to change the configuration path (i.e. where the vhost files go), modify: `System > Server Config > [Server Name] > Web > Nginx Vhost config dir`. If you have two copies of nginx installed, ensure the right one is being loaded via your init script. Try `which nginx` and `whereis nginx` to locate the installed copies. ISPConfig should (not quite certain that it does) launch the default one.

Comment: Great, I'll post it as an answer in that case.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the configuration path (i.e. where the vhost files go), modify:

```
System > Server Config > [Server Name] > Web > Nginx Vhost config dir
```

If you have two copies of nginx installed, ensure the right copy is being loaded via your init (or upstart) script.

- Use `which nginx` - to find the default copy (i.e. what is run by using just 'nginx' without  a path)
- Use `whereis nginx` to locate other installed copies and relevant directories.

ISPConfig should (not quite certain that it does) launch the default one - either directly, or by using an init script (or the services command).

If you are a bit more adventurous, you can modify the way that ISPConfig works (e.g. the default vhost layout) by looking in the following files:

- /usr/lib/ispconfig/server/conf/nginx_apps.vhost.master
- /usr/lib/ispconfig/server/plugins-enabled/nginx_plugin.inc.php